# How to select an option from a menu if the menu just appear when I start to type the option?

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, selenium-ide

Hy guys!

I`m having a problem using Selenium IDE, I need to select a product um a list, but this list just appear to me when I start to type the name of the product. I tried to do this the "common' way, using type > waitForVisible > clickAt, but when it type the menu not appears, and this is a problem for me, because the system just let me salve the new data if I choose this option from the menu.

Example of the menu:
If I need to choose an apple from a fruit table, I start to typing "ap" and then should appear a box with fruits that starts with "ap" like apple and apricot, and then I would choose the correct option from the menu.

If someone could help me I would apreciate this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced something similar.

Try using the *sendKeys* function. This simulates the manual typing effect and the results should show up.

The next step should be using the *select* command combined with a class identifier of the highlighted result (Generally the most relevant result *apple* in your case, should show up highlighted).

If you require more assistance, kindly share the page source. Hope this helps!